# How to create a new app in windows developer center

Tags: azure, push-notification, windows-store-apps, azure-notificationhub, windows-dev-center

Create a new app Not show in Windows Developer Center

I am Making a Windows Universal App in visual studio 2022
in this application get push notification Microsoft azure

push notification Microsoft azure to follow this documentation
[Azure Notification Hubs documentation For windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification)

this documentation showing steps in get Package SID and Security Key from Windows Developer Center in get to Create New App in configer and get both (Package SID and Security Key)

this is pass in Azure Notification Hub connect Windows Universal App Get push notifications

Comment: Have you check my reply about how to create a new app in windows developer center?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to register a developer account.

[Developer accounts in Partner Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/publish/partner-center/partner-center-developer-account)

Then Publish your UWP app in the Microsoft Store.

[Publish your app in the Microsoft Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/publish/publish-your-app/overview?pivots=store-installer-msix).

After publishing the UWP app, you can create your app in the Developer Center dashboard.

[Creating and managing apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/dashboard/creating-and-managing-apps)

Comment: this not working i have developer account  already

Comment: At which step did you encounter a problem?  Is there any error message?